# Which postcard mailing services are the best?

Tags: prints, travel, image-processing, service-recommendation, photolabs

I have noticed several sites offering to let me upload a photo, some text and an address. They will then print a postcard with the image and my text and mail it for me.

Some offer smartphone-apps and some offer printing services in many locations (I live in Europe, so a European location will give me much faster service).

I have found several:

- [Postagram](http://postagramapp.com/)
- [shoot it!](http://www.shootit.com/)
- [goPostal](http://www.printyourlife.com/)

It sounds perfect for vacations, but does anyone have any experience using such services?

Any recommendations for the best one?

Comment: What smartphone platform are you on? Do you want a smartphone app? Is that the goal?

Comment: @dpollitt: I would probably be using pictures from my DSLR or P&S, thus using my laptop with hotel wifi. So no, smartphone app would be a plus, but the important factors are speed (time until postcard reach destination), quality and reasonable price. But I do have an iPhone.

Comment: Only as another model: we do it the manual way. There is a fast-printing service/machines in nearly every modern city or vacation spot. We just print the pictures we selected, add a stamp and some personalized scribbles and send the newly-made postcards on their way ... (some places like the Canary Islands only offer 24h-service though ;) ).

Answer (score 2):

While I am not familiar with options outside of the United States, I have used Postagram for the iPhone.  I found it quite handy while traveling to Europe this summer.  I sent my family back a few postcards at $.99 each(they used to charge $1.99), and I also sent myself some back home.

They take about a week to process, but the quality is excellent. The biggest advantage I found was that I can do it very easily right from the iPhone app. Signup only took seconds, and once you enter in your credit card info once, they keep it on file for future purchases. I would have preferred that they used the Apple Store payment system so I didn't have to provide my credit card to a third party, but that is how they currently operate.

As far as print quality, I've only tried Postagram, but have found the quality to be quite nice. It is as good of quality as you can expect from a single print option like this. If you want to print 100 or 1000 post cards, you can get real offset printing that is quite a bit higher quality then this. But I do not know of a company that offers this for single postcards - due to cost and complexity.

**Some examples of the Postagram service** -

*Take note, these were sent through the mail for 5 days, so they get pretty torn up!*

[image]
[image]
[image]